# jQuery select before element that not as parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select button element before `my-form` class by jQuery. If you are careful, my button is not as a parent element.

```
<div>
    <button>Click</button>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" class="my-form">
</div>
```

Thank you very much indeed!

Comment: What do you mean with "select button"? What of the button are you trying to "select"?

Comment: are you trying to find the previous button from `$(.'my-form')`? Did you lookup `.prev()` and `.find()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to find the button from the input

```
$('input.my-form').parent().prev().find('button')
```

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  $('input.my-form').parent().prev().find('button').text("Button changed!")
}, 500)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button>button</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button>button</button>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" class="my-form">
</div>
```